# Django query for matching 'cousin' objects (with same grandparent)

Tags: django, querying

[image: Validation on this object]

I am trying to write some validations on form input and need to check that the instance being created doesn't already exist under the same grandparent. The field I am validating against isn't a primary key as it can exist outside the 'family'.
I can't seem to think of an appropriate query for this but so far I have the following which works:

```
existing_parents = Parent.objects.filter(grandparent=active_parent.grandparent)
for parent in existing_parents:
    existing_children = parent.children.all()
            for children in existing_children
                if existing_children.identifier == identifier:
                    self._errors["form_field"] = self.error_class(
                        ["That child already exists"]
                    )
                else: 
                    pass
```

Just wondered if there was a lookup I can do that simplifies it?

Comment: Can you share the model(s)? Exactly what are `Grandparent`, `Parent`, etc.? How do these relate with `ForeignKey`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can check this with:

```
Child.objects.filter(
    identifier=identifier,
    parent__grandparent__parents=active_parent
).exists()
```

We here thus start from the `Child` model, move up to the `grandparent` (with `parent__grandparent` and then move down with `__parents`, and check if such identifier already exists). Here `parents` is the value for the [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) of the `ForeignKey`s from `Parent` to `GrandParent`, and from `Child` to `Parent`. If you did not specify a `related_query_name=…` parameter, it will use the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for that name, and if you did not specify that either, then it uses the name of the model in lowercase.

This will of course check *all* grandchildren, including the one you want to edit and already exists in the database. You thus can *exclude* a `Child` that aready exists with:

```
Child.objects.exclude(
    pk=pk_of_child_to_exclude
).filter(
    identifier=identifier,
    parent__grandparent__parents=active_parent
).exists()
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying to put this into practice but it seems to call the error whenever it finds an instance with the matching identifier, even if from another gradnparent object (which I don't want). Maybe I should post the models..

Comment: @fdeboo: are you sure it is not simply the same child like the one you aim to update? Note that the children can be of the *same* parent. So they can be the same child, a sibling, or a cousin.

Comment: @fdeboo: that is exactly why, if you want to *update* a child, you should exclude the one you are updating at that moment, since otherwise the query is trivially true: the child you aim to update of course has a cousin with the same identifier: himself.

Comment: I am sure as this is the validation before the child object is saved/created. Let me double check I'm not doing something stupid

Comment: @fdeboo: I think I misunderstood the question. Normally it should be fixed now.

Comment: Is it not because the Child model refers to all children regardless of grandparent?

Comment: @fdeboo: I made a mistake by not filtering on the `active_parent`, normally with the extra filter, that should be fixed.